# How to use pygame.time.get_ticks

Tags: python, pygame

How do you make something disappear after a certain amount of time using pygame.time.get_ticks? I am trying to draw a line, then make it disappear after 2 seconds, and I have been experimenting with get_ticks because I was told it would work, but since it counts the time starting from when the code was initialized, I can't seem to pinpoint the exact time I draw the circle and 2 seconds after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you want to start drawing the line, call `pygame.time.get_ticks` and store the result, let's call it `start_time`.

Then you call  `pygame.time.get_ticks` every frame and compare that value to the value you stored.

So if `pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time > 2000` you know two seconds passed, and you stop drawing the line.

Here's a simple example:

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0
    start_time = None

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))

        if start_time and pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time < 2000:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0), (500, 500), 10)
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (500, 0), (0, 500), 10)

        pygame.display.update()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I keep getting the error builtins.AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_ticks'. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: You call `get_ticks` on an integer instead of the `pygame.time` modul. Make sure you're using the correct variables.